# Не создаются ярлыки приложения после запуска на реальном устройстве из Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ярлыки

Всем привет! Столкнулся с проблемой: после нажатия кнопки Run 'app' и выбора подключенного планшета приложение спокойно устанавливается, и запускается.

Но вот беда: мне нужно протестировать как будет вести себя приложение после перезапуска, а ни на главном экране, ни в менюшке со всёма приложениями моего нет. Хотя в настройках => приложения оно светится.

Comment: Вы нас заинтриговали уже!!! `Manifest` свой в студию!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3bfWXX4m Однако решение оказалось крайне простым (ответ @ЮрийСПб).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Проверьте, что у одной из активити приложения есть следующий IntentFilter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Вы как всегда правы :D удалил свой ответ)

Comment: @iFr0z, не факт, что я прав) Может у ТС приложение без активити вовсе)